# How do I properly map array into <Text> (React native)

Tags: arrays, react-native

I have an array that I need to map out in `<Text>`. This is what I've got in `render()`

```
categories.map(category => <Text>{category.testHeader}</Text>
```

But it doesn't print anything. I guess `<Text>` needs to be in `render()` right? So I tried adding it in a function to be called in `render`. Like this:

```
function myfunc() {
    return categories.map(category => <Text>{category.testHeader}</Text>)
}
```

Then in `render()`:

```
<View>
    {myfunc()}
</View>
```

But then the compiler said `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. SO tips told me to put write:

```
function myfunc() {
    if (this.props.data) {
        return categories.map(category => <Text>{category.testHeader}</Text>)
    }
}
```

But now the compiler tells me that `data` is undefined. Not sure what to do here... :/

Comment: is categories a global variable? did you mean this.props.categories or this.props.data.categories?

Comment: `categories`, where it come from ? should be props, local state, private variable, etc. do you mean `this.props.data.categories`?

Answer (score 7):

You can use like this:

```
var categories = [{ id: 0, text: 'hasan' }, 
    { id: 1, text: 'erkan' },
    { id: 2, text: 'veli' }];

export default class App extends Component {
renderCategories() {
    return categories.map((item, index) => <Text key={index}>{item.text}</Text>);
}
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {this.renderCategories()}
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Firstly defined the data to be []. Then assign categories array to data and try to use it. If required use JSON.parse(data)